# Tensorflow how to create a dataset from tupple of input and output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I want to create a dataset which is a list of tupple, which the first value is the input (also a tupple), and the second value is the expected output.

I have a list:

```
mylist = list()
```

and in a while loop I create the list with:

```
mylist.append(  ([input, input_mask], expected_output) )
```

the shape of `input`, `input_mask` and `expected_output` is `(800,120)`

(I want that the model will get as an input the `input` and the `input_mask`, and calculate the loss with the `expected_output`)

In the end I want to turn `mylist` into a dataset for the model.

how can I create the dataset?

Comment: for example as a dictonary. with keys `input`,  `input_mask` and `labels`. Hence, `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input, input_mask,, labels))`

Comment: @Oscar but when i do this, i get an error `ValueError: Layer model_5 expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors.` (`shape=(3, 800, 120`) . it takes all the tupple of the 3 tensors and pass it to the model as one input. how I force it to pass only the two parameters in the tupple?

Comment: with a lambda function, using indexing, splitting the tuple.